# SwiftUI: Shadow on view in VStack?

Tags: swiftui, shadow

I have the following code:

```
struct ViewA: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color(.yellow))
    }
}
    
struct ViewB: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color(.white))
    }
}
    
struct ViewC: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color(.blue))
    }
}


struct TestView: View {


    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                
                ViewA()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.width/4, alignment: .center)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10)
                
                ViewB()
                
                ViewC()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 0)
                    .opacity(0.8)
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

It draws:

[image]

The shadow at the bottom Blue over White view (ViewC over ViewB) shows up.
I want the yellow view (ViewA) to drop a shadow on top of the white view.

I want the white view to appear as if it were under both the top view (yellow) and the bottom view (blue).

I am not sure how to organize the views so that the top view also drops shadow on the middle view.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply zindex modifier to ViewA. For example .zIndex(.infinity). It will put ViewA on top of everything.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/zindex(_:)

Comment: This works great and it does not require to mess with the y offset on ViewB. This means I can do away with adding ZStack and moving ViewB around...

Answer (score 1):

If you place the views in a `ZStack` with ViewB behind ViewA and ViewC you will see the shadow:

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    ZStack {
        ViewB()
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ViewA()
                .frame(
                    width: geo.size.width,
                    height: geo.size.width/4,
                    alignment: .center)
                .shadow(
                    color: .black,
                    radius: 10,
                    x: 0, y: 0)
            Spacer()
            ViewC()
                .frame(
                    width: geo.size.width,
                    height: 100,
                    alignment: .center)
                .shadow(
                    color: .black,
                    radius: 10,
                    x: 0, y: 0)
                .opacity(0.8)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Makes sense. However, ViewB's size now is the full height and not stacked between A and C anymore. I need B to be stacked in between A and C.

Comment: I applied an y offset to B to match ViewA's height. That positions ViewB correctly after applying your answer.